# React GetStream Error: Both secret and user tokens are not set

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io, getstream-chat

When a user navigates to my chat page, I am getting the following error message:

> Error: Both secret and user tokens are not set.

When the user navigates to my chat page, I am passing the userId as a param. I would like to use the userId to call queryUsers() to get the user object from GetStream and then pass the user object as a param in my connectUser call.

However, when I include the queryUsers() call, I get the following error message. When the queryUsers() is not included and I provide the connectUser() call with a hardcoded user object (see testUserObject in code below), the error disappears. Full error message below:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Both secret and user tokens are not set. Either client.connectUser wasn't called or client.disconnect was called
    at TokenManager.getToken (token_manager.ts:140:1)
    at StreamChat._getToken (client.ts:2621:1)
    at StreamChat._enrichAxiosOptions (client.ts:2579:1)
    at _callee5$ (client.ts:936:1)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:1)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:125:1)
    at Generator.next (regeneratorRuntime.js:69:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
```

The below is the code for my chat page:

```
useEffect(() => {
async function init() {
  const chatClient = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey);

  const response = await chatClient.queryUsers({
    id: { $in: [testUserId] },
  });
  const userObject = response.users[0];

  await chatClient.connectUser(
    userObject,
    chatClient.devToken(userObject.id)
  );

  const channel = chatClient.channel("messaging", "react-talk", {
    image: "https://getstream.io/random_svg/?id=john&name=John",
    name: "React Talk",
    members: [userObject.id],
  });
  await channel.watch();

  setChannel(channel);
  setClient(chatClient);
}

init();

return () => {
  if (client) {
    client.disconnectUser();
  }
};
```

}, []);

My GetStream project is in development mode, GetStream authentication is turned off, and I am using the prebuilt chat ui components from the GetStream React SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the code is that you need to authenticate the user before calling other methods such as `queryUsers`.

What this means is that your code flow should look something like this:

```
const chatClient = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey);

await chatClient.connectUser(
  'userid',
  'user-token'
);

/* Rest of your code */
```

That also means that you can't find the `id` of the user by querying all users from the client in order to authenticate someone.